# Passing parameters to shell_exec using php

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have a php file like:

```
<?php 
    $name="abc@xyz.com";
    $Result = Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -File ".\filename.ps1" $name');
    ?>
```

I want to insert variable `$name` in `shell_exec()` command.
How will i do that?
I have tried `{$name}`, `'$name'`, `'.$name.'`

Answer (score 0):

The `$name` is not parsed while php execution. Can you try this below, i think below code will be helpful

```
 $name="abc@xyz.com";
 $Result = Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -File ".\filename.ps1" '.$name);
```